# JQuery .attr() not working with specified IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to JQuery(and JS). I am trying to make a very simple thing that will change my image attribute and for some reason it's not working. I've been breaking my head over this for the past hour and I can't seem to find a logical reason for why it's not working. I've tried `$("#thumbnail-"+id).attr(...)` as well and it doesn't work. I couldn't figure out why. So I broke things down to the code below, still doesn't work. For some reason the attribute doesn't change.

**Here's my code( I commented it to make things easier):**

```
$(".innerImage").click(function (e) {
    var imageName = ($(this).find('img').attr('src').split('/'))[2]; //returns something like 4.jpg
    var id = (imageName.split('.'))[0]; //returns just 4 (from 4.jpg)
    var thumb = "#thumbnail-"+id; //returns #thumbnail-4
    var thumbnail = 'product/thumb/'+id+'.jpg'; //returns product/thumb/4.jpg
    var full = 'product/full_size/'+id+'.jpg'; //returns product/full_size/4.jpg
    $(thumb).attr('src', thumbnail); //This is the crazy part that doesn't work
    alert(1); //Did a trace and it reached here.

});
```

**Stuff that worked but I cannot use them:**

So the weird part here is that the following worked:

```
$('img').attr('src', 'product/thumb/test.jpg');
$('#thumbnail-4').attr('src', 'product/thumb/test.jpg'); //this worked perfect. Notice how it's just that specific id, where I didn't concatenate the 4 using the method in my code. The latter is more general
```

However the above(latter) one messes up all my images and not the specific one I want which is #thumbnail-id(where id = 1,...). Could anyoune point out what I'm doing wrong. The only thing I can see is that it's not allowing me to concatenate my strings and use them.

**Edit: HTML**

```
<div id='imageArea-4' class='imageArea'>
    <div class='leftSide'>
            "<div class='innerImage'>
                <img src='product/thumb/4.jpg' />
            </div>


            <div class='innerImage'>
                <img src='product/thumb/4-002.jpg' />
            </div>      
    </div>

    <div class='rightSide' id='rightSide-4'>        
            <img id='thumbnail-4' src='product/thumb/4.jpg' />
            <button class='zoomImg intense' data-image='product/full_size/4.jpg' id='zoomImg-4'></button>                       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `'product/full_size/'+id+'jpg'` should give you `product/full_size/4jpg`, without the dot. Use the developer tools to inspect the element. And please be specific, what does "`attr()` not working" mean?  You don't see a new image? The `src` value on the element is not changed at all? Hell kittens appear and mewl you to death?

Comment: @Amadan `For some reason the attribute doesn't change.`So yeah, the src atrribute is not changed at all.  And thanks for pointing out the 4.jpg edited it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"messes up all my images and not the specific one I want"*? Messes them up how?

Comment: There is zero chance that `$('#thumbnail-4').attr(...)` and `id='4'; $('#thumbnail-' + id).attr(...)` will do something different in the same context. Re-check your `id` with `console.log("[" + id + "]")` (make sure you don't have any rogue space issues).

Comment: @Phil Here it's just to show that I don't want to have all my `<img>` attributes changed. Just the ones with `thumbnail-id`. When I tried to replace `thumbnail-id` with just `img` all the attributes were changed, thus a big mess up

Comment: @Amadan that's why I've spent one hour on it and can't find a solution. I use `$('stuffHere'+id)` all the time and they work.

Comment: Oh, by *"above one"* you meant the *latter* code snippet. Only thing I can think of is that `id` does not get assigned what you think it does. You should set a breakpoint in the code and step through, checking each value.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? I'd like to toss this into a fiddle to work out for you.

Comment: @Amadan console.log shows no spaces.

Comment: You may also have duplicate elements with `id="thumbnail-1"` (or whatever those specific, not working IDs are)

Comment: @Phil If there were repeating thumbnail, a direct use of `('#thumbnail-4')` for example, would not have worked as well. However a direct use works.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant only specific IDs weren't working

Comment: It's quite specific, since all that needs to work is "#thumnail-id" and not "img" (which is the general img tag for all images).

Comment: I noticed in your code comment you have `var thumb = "#thumbnail-"+id; //returns thumbnail-4`. Shouldn't that be *" returns #thumbnail-4"*? Just a typo?

Comment: Well, you need to post some HTML, preferably in a JSFiddle example that replicates the problem

Comment: I made a fiddle for you here but of course it works as expected ~ http://jsfiddle.net/ubdkaeur/

Comment: Well, clicking the first `.innerImage` won't do anything (other than set the `#thumbnail-4` image to be the same) and clicking the second one won't do anything as there is no `id="thumbnail-4-002"` element

Comment: We assume you have 2 divs rightSide one "<div class='rightSide' id='rightSide-4'>" and another one "<div class='rightSide' id='rightSide-4-002'>", right?

Comment: Yeah. Both are there @Giuseppe

Comment: Add console.log("value is: "+$(thumb).attr('src')); and you'll see if it gets what you expect.

Comment: You're right, @Phil now it works. Looks like I had a logical error and I didn't properly trace it. It's all working now. Thanks

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks. value is: undefined showed me where I went wrong. It's like Phil said.

Comment: Please provide a FIDDLE

Comment: *"It's like Phil said"* - Wait, what did I say?

Comment: There is no id="thumbnail-4-002".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What looks to be happening is the following:

When you select the first image, `4.jpg`, the `id` gets set to `4`. In which case you're able to target `'#thumbnail-4'` correctly. However, when you click on the second image, `4-002.jpg`, the `id` gets set to `4-002`. So the script is looking to update the source of `#thumbnail-4-002` which does not exist.

I put together this fiddle to show the disconnect.
http://jsfiddle.net/fd2cwm8y/

My suggestion for this would be to give the `thumbnail` a unique ID so it does not depend on the `id` value you're retrieving from the clicked image like I have thrown together here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7qt8wzot/

I hope this helps!

Comment: I fixed it already but this is the correct answer. Thanks :)